# Why are the IPtables and kernel module versions not matching in Yocto Linux?

Tags: iptables, kernel-module, embedded-linux, yocto-project

I am trying to add IPtables to a Yocto Linux image but I think versions of compiled modules and modules needed for IPtables do not match. IPtables is looking for modules under `/lib/modules/4.9.88` but kernel modules are under `/lib/modules/5.4.94`.

```
root@imx6ullevk:~# iptables -L
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.88+g5e23f9d61147
iptables v1.8.5 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.

root@imx6ullevk:/lib/modules# ls -al
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root           240 Apr  6 11:50 .
drwxr-xr-x    7 root     root          4528 Apr  6 11:50 ..
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          1208 Apr  6 11:50 5.4.94+g4b9631852aa7

root@imx6ullevk:/lib/modules/5.4.94+g4b9631852aa7# cat modules.builtin | grep ip_
kernel/net/ipv4/ip_tunnel.ko
kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_tables.ko
```

Is there anything I could try to fix this?

I use the following steps to create an image. I have also tried newer branches than Gatesgarth (Thud, Master, Zeus, Warrior…) and making the modules included and modular but the problem consists.

```
repo init -u https://github.com/Freescale/fsl-community-bsp-platform -b gatesgarth;
repo sync;
DISTRO=fslc-framebuffer MACHINE=imx6ullevk source setup-environment build;

#Add necessary recipies to the local.conf
echo 'MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RRECOMMENDS += "kernel-modules"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " \
    packagegroup-core-ssh-openssh \
    openssh-sftp-server \
    iptables "' >> build/conf/local.conf;

#Add ip_tables modules
bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel;

#Build the image
bitbake core-image-base;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reboot. If it still doesn't work probably the "actual" `/boot` filesystem that the bootloader uses was not mounted on `/boot` correctly when you upgraded the kernel. (Or, when the bootloader was installed, `/boot` isn't mounted with the filesystem you desired to use.)

Comment: I was forgetting to update the zImage in MFG tool.